# MSMQ - Time To Be Received Timing Out

Tags: msmq

I am sending the same transactional message via C# to 3 transactional MSMQ queues 
I have set the time to be received from 5second up to 900seconds.

Dead letter logging is on

All the permissions on all 3 queues are identical
The target queues are:
2 private queues on the sending machine
1 public queue on a remote machine

No matter how many times I repeat this, 2 of the sends fail.  I have verified when sending the message into MSMQ the time to be received is 5s.

1 private queue on sending machine works
the other 2 wind up in the dead letter queue

How can I troubleshoot this?  It's always the same queue that works and the same queue that fails no matter which order they are sent in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, the services reading from the other queues weren't running.  Apparently to be properly 'received' something has to do the receiving!